# How to convert xml files to OWL using java?

Tags: xml, jena, owl, ontology, owl-api

I wanted to convert xml file to an ontology. 
I have an input file in xml format and I need to convert it into a owl file 
Can anyone let me know what the suitable method is to do this using jena api in java?

Comment: Hello, what methods have you attempted to convert XML to OWL using java?

Comment: Then hire a developer to do it. We are not here to write code for people.

Comment: For a question to be valid you have to provide the exact problem you are facing (input sample, expected output sample) and of course show some minimal effort.

Comment: You are probably better off writing an xslt transformation, rather than do it in java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for this problem, it depends on the content of the XML file, its intended meaning and what the ontology is meant to represent.

1) does the file contain individuals or instances? In that case, you need an existing ontology to provide you with the vocabulary, and then you can write a translator. This can be java, xslt, or anything else you're confident with.

2) does the file contain an ontology in any standard format? In this case, conversion to OWL might be possible with existing tools, but we can't tell which ones without more information.

Comment: All the xml files contains sentence based simple mathematic questions, and that should be converted to OWL. 1) Yes it contains individuals and yes i think there should be an existing ontology and it should update according to the provided xml files. 2) I use OWL/XML format.

Comment: As i'm new to the Ontology I haven't any idea how i write a translater for this. Is it easier to convert xml to xslt and then convert to owl? Is it possible to code it using owlapi?

Comment: All of this is possible but there is no prepackaged solution to do so. You'll need to first get the ontology you plan to use to describe your individuals, then get familiar on how to create the OWL assertions with the framework you choose - owlapi is OK for this. When you say OWL/XML, do you mean that's the format you want for the output?

Comment: Yes i mean OWL./XML format.                                                                                                            <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Item"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="#Has"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <DataProperty IRI="#Name"/>
    </Declaration>                                                                                             This is a part of that file

Comment: Is it possible to translte to OWL using XSLT transformation?

Comment: If your XML file is OWL/XML, it already is OWL. No translations needed.

Comment: I mean i want to convert xml tags to Ontology

Comment: Load the file with OWL API and save it as RDF/XML. The owl api website has examples on how to do that. If you get errors, pleas open an issue on GitHub showing input file and errors.

Comment: I tried to convert RDF/XML to OWL/XML. It is succeddful. But cannot convert Xml file to OWL/XML format. It doesn't get the correct output.

Comment: @lgnazio: I posted the codings that I did the conversion

Answer (score -1):

public class API {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException, FileNotFoundException {

    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();


    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\jin\\Desktop\\ProtoType\\\\New Folder\\\\MathsQuestion.xml"); 
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);


    OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology);
    OWLOntologyDocumentTarget documentTarget = new SystemOutDocumentTarget();
    manager.saveOntology(ontology, format, new SystemOutDocumentTarget());

    System.out.println(" format1: " + format);

    OWLXMLOntologyFormat owlxmlFormat = new OWLXMLOntologyFormat(); //owl/xml format
    OWLOntologyDocumentTarget documentTarget2 = new SystemOutDocumentTarget();

    if (format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) {
        owlxmlFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat());
    }

    manager.saveOntology(ontology, owlxmlFormat, new SystemOutDocumentTarget());
    System.out.println(" format2: " + owlxmlFormat);
```